# PHP not modifying header info

Tags: php, soap, header, token

I am logging into a server with soap and retreiving a token, no problem....

I then add the token to the soap:header.

This is what I am trying create.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <WSAuthorization xmlns="http://url.com/testing/">
      <Token>string</Token>
    </WSAuthorization>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <ImportDrugTest xmlns="http://url.com/testing/">
      <specimenID>int</specimenID>
      <midasNumber>string</midasNumber>
      <specimenComments>string</specimenComments>
      <nonRXDrugsUsed>string</nonRXDrugsUsed>
      <testCode>string</testCode>
      <testDate>dateTime</testDate>
      <testResult>string</testResult>
      <collectionDate>dateTime</collectionDate>
      <lastName>string</lastName>
      <firstName>string</firstName>
      <middleName>string</middleName>
      <CRUDFlag>string</CRUDFlag>
    </ImportDrugTest>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

This is what I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://url.com/testing/">
    <soap-env:header>
        <ns1:wsauthorization />
    </soap-env:header>
    <soap-env:body>
        <ns1:importdrugtest>
            <ns1:specimenid>605431024</ns1:specimenid>
            <ns1:midasnumber>7700MD2005000001.00</ns1:midasnumber>
            <ns1:specimencomments>Miscellaneous</ns1:specimencomments>
            <ns1:nonrxdrugsused>N/A</ns1:nonrxdrugsused>
            <ns1:testcode>025000</ns1:testcode>
            <ns1:testdate>2012-09-24</ns1:testdate>
            <ns1:testresult>Negative</ns1:testresult>
            <ns1:collectiondate>2012-09-25</ns1:collectiondate>
            <ns1:lastname>Last</ns1:lastname>
            <ns1:firstname>First</ns1:firstname>
            <ns1:middlename>Middle</ns1:middlename>
            <ns1:crudflag>C</ns1:crudflag>
        </ns1:importdrugtest>
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

Here is my code. **Note:** I have already stared a new SoapClient() and regeived the token.

```
$ns = 'http://url.com/testing/';
// $headerParams = array('WSAuthorization'=>array('token'=>$token)); tried this also
$headerParams = array('token'=>$token); 
$header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'WSAuthorization', $headerParams);       

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$param = array('ImportTest' => array( 
                'specimenID'  => '0605431024',
                'midasNumber' => '7700MD2005000001.00',
                'county' => '03',
                'site' => '00',
                'specimenComments' => 'Miscellaneous',
                'nonRXDrugsUsed' => 'N/A',
                'testCode'  => '025000',
                'testDate' => '2012-09-24',
                'testResult' => 'Negative',
                'collectionDate' => '2012-09-25',
                'lastName' => 'Last',
                'firstName' => 'First',
                'middleName'  => 'Middle',
                'CRUDFlag'  => 'C'
            ));

$result = $client->__soapCall('ImportDrugTest', $param);
```

**Update 12/31/14**:

I modified the code and added print_r($header):

```
$ns = "http://url.com/testing/";
$headerParams = array('token'=>$token); 
$header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'WSAuthorization', $headerParams);       
print_r($header);
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header)); // even tried $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

I get this:

```
SoapHeader Object
(
    [namespace] => http://url.com/testing/
    [name] => WSAuthorization
    [data] => Array
        (
            [token] => UDjVSzGt9J4fKuRuoFHau3gy4CoLo//VlnuZv5oy5tjKPffIeSc+dx7EEDIfosVkVHDD0G/ZBANnCzPmRBo6CIusRL5rak5QdYI9jD7209c=
        )

    [mustUnderstand] => 
)
```

But __getLastRequest() gives me this:

```
<soap-env:header>
    <ns1:wsauthorization />
</soap-env:header>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: check out documentation and comments about header http://php.net/manual/en/soapheader.soapheader.php

Comment: I did check out the documentation. Even tried adding the header in the _soapCall('ImportDrugTest', $param, null, $header)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$headerParams = array('Token'  => $token);
$header     = new SoapHeader($NameSpace, 'WSAuthorization', $headerParams, false);
```

The problem I was having was caused by the token not being parsed from the response.